# PHP script doesn't launch local shell script

Tags: php

Actually, I am working with Lighttpd Web Server on an embedded Linux platform with PHP 7.0.

My goal is simple:
How can I write some values from my webpage to my local file ?

To do that, I did:

HTML PAGE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test1.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
</form
</body>
</html>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   exec("/var/www/html/test.sh");
?>
```

and at least SHELL SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/$USER
touch testFile && echo "this is a test" > testFile
```

All my directory is under www-data (User & Group), and the permissions are set to chmod 750 to each of the scripts.

So, when I launch the PHP and the shell script alone, it works fine without problems.

Example:

```
./test.sh
```

or

```
php test1.php
```

But no luck with the web page.
It doesn't work.

Do you have an idea of my problem ?
I think its because of the permissions user and group

tahnks.

Comment: The userid(aka the web server) that runs the script probably does not have write access to the user directory. Check the web server logs for any errors.

Comment: I do agree with @JasonK. With apache, the default settings only given access to write in the document root directory and the directory under this directory. Try to under your document root to see lighttpd follow same rules, after just need to look how to set your chances.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? A gui program is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

exec("/bin/bash /var/www/html/test.sh");
```

the php process does not have a bash. You must specify it in the command

Comment: Hi Denis, Thank you for your proposal, but it doesn't work. I think it is due to permissions with users & groups. 
The $USER is the owner of the computer (Embedded Electronic Computer), and the group is www-data. But I don't know what to do to work with the scripts...